# Problem with typing column vector

Tags: columns

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym, amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

On différentie l'égalité: $f(a,b) = f(x,y) = f(x, \phi (x))$ par rapport à $x$:
 \begin{align}
    df_{(x, \phi x)} & \circ \begin{bmatrix}
           \text{Id}_X \\
           d\phi_x
         \end{bmatrix} = 0 
\Leftrightarrow \big( df_{(x,\phi(x))|X},df_{(x,\phi(x))|Y} \big) \circ \begin{bmatrix}
               \text{Id}_X \\
               d\phi_x
             \end{bmatrix} = 0
     \end{align}

\end{document}
```

I got this output: 
[image]

Why is there "(1)" at the end of the line even though it didn't appear in the code? How to get rid of it?

Comment: `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` instead of `align. Remove the `&` that serves no purpose in that `align` (and would be wrong in `equation`).

Comment: Use  the `align*` environment (with a star).

Comment: @Francis: your link answers exactly my question. However I'm not sure if it is duplicate (general question versus specific example)

Comment: @egreg,@Bernard: thanks a lot. Both solutions work!

Comment: @SiXUlm: Incidentally, you shouldn't use `times` which is obsolete and doesn't change the math font (Computer Modern is rather ugly with Times). Use `mathptmx` instead, or, better, the pair `newtxmath, newtxtext`.

Comment: if you really always want no equation number for a one-line display, you can use `\[ ... `\]`.  the environment `equation*` is exactly equivalent to that.  the `*` specifies that no equation number is to be applied to a display math environment.